# Fault Tolerance in Ignite Services

Tags: ignite, gridgain

I have deployed ignite services()(some job to be performed on ignite nodes) on 4 ignite nodes. If one node fails and job is in midway of execution, I want other node to take over this job and continue executing it. How can we handle this type of failure in case of service grids? I have read about fail over SPI and check pointing SPI, which of these can be used in my case? are there any examples for same?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Failover, checkpointing, etc. are parts of Compute Grid [1]. And from what I hear, it fits your use case much better than Service Grid.

[1] https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/compute-grid

Comment: In my service grid code I have already divided tasks across ignite nodes that are running, whereas compute grid tells that task is run in distributed fashion(split and merge). But in my case I want to run only same code on all nodes(there is no task to divide and merge). So how can I use compute grid to run same code across all nodes, same as service grid if i want to move my code from service to compute grid?

Comment: Take a look at `IgniteCompute` API. It allows to execute not only fully pledged fork-join tasks, but also simple closures like runnables and callables. There is also `broadcast` method that can be useful for you.